# Step into custom nuget c++ package

Tags: c++, debugging, nuget, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to release a C++ nuget package into our company Nuget feed. The problem is that we can't step into functions during debugging (F11). We need to be able to debug inside the package sources but it seems i cannot made it work.

I enabled in VS the option "Debug not only my code", included the generated vc110.pdb files in the package and finally added in the .nuspec the line

> <repository type="git" url="http://xxxx" />

Unfortunately, VS17 does not step into the code of my package. We are pretty desperate and we really need a solution to this problem in order to make our toolchain leaner.

This is a C++ question so please do not link me to C#/.NET solutions because they don't work.

NOTE 1: When i pack with nuget i do not use the -Symbols option because it generates 2 packages and the second one cannot be pushed on our nuget feed (dupikcated package)

NOTE 2: I looked into the /SourceLink option but it seems to be supported only in C#

NOTE 3: I cannot use the .vcxproj when packing (it does not work, nuget says that i didn't give it any input file so i have to use my own .nuspec:

```
 <package >
  <metadata>
    <id>x</id>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>x</authors>
    <projectUrl>yyy</projectUrl>
    <description>static .lib</description>
    <tags>native</tags>
    <repository type="git" url="yyy" />
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="include\**\*.*" target="include" /> 
    <file src="x64\**\*.lib" target="lib\x64" /> 
    <file src="x64\**\*.pdb" target="lib\x64" /> 
    <file src="build\**\*.*" target="build" /> 
  </files>
</package>
```

NOTE 4: Ours GIT repo is on a Azure Devops TFS machine

NOTE5 : We are using VS17 but compiling with vc110 toolset (yeah know, don't comment on that please)

Thanks all